# url in multi languages

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

Right now I'm working on a project, which has a multi lingual project i.e. English, Chinese, Danish, Korean etc. The page URL must be changed based on a selected language. Like :

```
English : example.com/pages/fullpage
Chinese : example.com/ch/頁面/整頁
Danish : example.com/dk/sider/fuldside
```

I have read the CakePhp 3.x document, but I can't get a proper answer for it. I do it through routing.
Like :

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/pages/fullpage',   ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'fullpage'] );
    $routes->connect('/頁面/整頁',   ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'fullpage'] );
    $routes->connect('/sider/fuldside',   ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'fullpage'] );
});
```

It works perfectly, but I want reliable concept because in this scenario, I need to define the routing for all actions.

So if you have any thoughts about this please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing thousands of routes just u[se the translation methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#using-translation-functions) and [toggle the language](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#changing-the-locale-at-runtime) on whatever parameter you use to set it:

```
// Detect and set language before, we use a middleware
$routes->connect('/' . __d('routes', 'pages') . '/' . __d('routes', 'fullpage'), [ /*...*/]);
```

That's the way we use for ~20 languages on our site.